# Gitlab Status API: is too long (maximum is 255 characters)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I have an issue updating some projects Status in Gitlab via its API,
I'm getting this body response:

```
Response body: {
      "message" : {
            "target_url" : [ "is too long (maximum is 255 characters)" ]
      }
}
```

This update is done via a Jenkins plugin to update the status of each branch/commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened because of the limit of a field `target_url`, from your side nothing much you can do to fix that, unless you make the project name/path shorter.

There's an ongoing issue on Gitlab to increase the limit for some fields: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/23868#note_507841032